# numeric to writeBytes / Java

Tags: java

I need to get a numeric from a table in database and put it a ChannelBuffer in a field with 4 bytes of width.

The number can be 1 to 9999 eg. 237 and in ChannelBuffer I need to fill the 4 bytes.

```
ChannelBuffer bufcmd = ChannelBuffers.directBuffer(4);
bufcmd.writeByte(0x00); // 1º digit of 4 bytes
bufcmd.writeByte(0x00); // 2º digit of 4 bytes
bufcmd.writeByte(0x00); // 3º digit of 4 bytes
bufcmd.writeByte(0x01); // 4º digit of 4 bytes
```

How can I fill this directly with 237 value?

The entire code is:

```
String strcmd = "dyd#"; //from database

ChannelBuffer bufcmd = ChannelBuffers.directBuffer(100);

bufcmd.writeByte(0x78);
bufcmd.writeByte(0x78);
bufcmd.writeByte((5 + strcmd.length()));
bufcmd.writeByte(0x80);
bufcmd.writeByte((4 + strcmd.length()));



// TODO: convert 1 to 9999 to HEX 
// (id of command from database eg: 3)
// but filling 4 bytes
bufcmd.writeByte(0x00);
bufcmd.writeByte(0x00);
bufcmd.writeByte(0x00);
bufcmd.writeByte(0x03);


bufcmd.writeBytes(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(strcmd, CharsetUtil.US_ASCII));
bufcmd.writeShort(buf.readUnsignedShort());
bufcmd.writeShort(Crc.crc16Ccitt(bufcmd.toByteBuffer(2, 4)));
bufcmd.writeByte(0x0D);
bufcmd.writeByte(0x0A);
channel.write(bufcmd);
```

Comment: What's `ChannelBuffer`?

Comment: You might say whether the "digits" are supposed to be ASCII encoded decimal digit characters, or decimal digits in binary (0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x07) and "first" and "fourth" isn't really precise, one uses terms like "most significant" etc.

Comment: Hi, is decimal digits in binary, I need to put a sequence of (0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01) to send 0001 you know

Comment: take a look of all code

Comment: And to send 11, you want 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0B?

Comment: So look at part one of my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This converts to big endian, binary:

```
   int theNumber = 237;
   byte[] buf = new byte[4];
   for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
   buf[3 - i] = (byte)(theNumber & 0xFF);
       theNumber = theNumber >> 8;
   }
```

Note that java.io.DataOutputStream and similar classes have method writeInt(int v) and similar methods for other types, which simplifies tasks like the one you appear to have considerabls.

The code below converts to decimal ASCII, most significant digit first, leading zeros:

```
   int theNumber = 237;
   byte[] buf = new byte[4];
   for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
   buf[3 - i] = (byte)(theNumber % 10 + 0x30);
       theNumber = theNumber / 10;
   }
```

Comment: how can I put it in the ChannelBuffer? like bufcmd.writeBytes(buf);

Comment: I put your code inside a for for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { bufcmd.writeByte(buf[i]); } and the value returned is 20307 and theNumber is 237

Comment: Which code? How? It seems you have mixed my two versions, which is NOT advisable.

Comment: You are storing one decimal digit per byte. This way, 237 will result in 4 bytes 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x07. - Last try: if the number is 237, what should be in these 4 bytes, hexadecimal notation please.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing which encoding etc you want in your bufcmd, I'm going to take a wild guess that "whatever String is using is okay"

```
int theNumber = 237; // The value
String theString = Integer.toString(theNumber); //The string representation of the value
for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
{
      bufcmd.writeByte( theString.charAt(i) );
}
```

Added: A full implementation which takes into account string lengths and adds zero padding and also translates the character into an integer, if you do not need this, remove the Character.getNumericValue() call that wraps around the character..

```
int theNumber = 237; // The value
String theString = Integer.toString(theNumber); //The string representation of the value
int len = theString.length(); //Bytes in the string
int requiredLen = 4; // 3 = 0003, 42 = 0042
int padding = requiredLen-len; //How many 0 we need to send first

while( padding-- > 0 )
{
    bufcmd.writeByte( 0 );
}

for(int i=0; i<len;i++)
{
    bufcmd.writeByte( Character.getNumericValue(theString.charAt(i)) );
}
```

You can also calculate the value of a position instead of translating it to a string using Math.pow.

Here is a test to prove that the method works.
http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        int theNumber = 237; // The value
        String theString = Integer.toString(theNumber); //The string representation of the value
        int len = theString.length(); //Bytes in the string
        int requiredLen = 4; // 3 = 0003, 42 = 0042
        int padding = requiredLen-len; //How many 0 we need to send first

        while( padding-- > 0 )
        {
            System.out.println( 0 );
        }

        for(int i=0; i<len;i++)
        {
            System.out.println( Character.getNumericValue(theString.charAt(i)) );
        }        

     }
}
```

Comment: What about the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: Should be quite obvious, this demonstrates the principle, the actual implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @DusteD but if the number have two digits ? eg: 23 my buffer expect 4 digits how can I do?

Comment: @DusteD with your implementation the code returned valu 20307 instead 237 what can be wrong?

Comment: @cristianormoraes I do not know, I just tested it on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php and it outputs 0237 on there. - I just opdated the example to correct a typo, copy paste the code to see for yourself.